# Saving Large Strings in MySQL / Java / Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to save a json document into a mysql 8 database. This json document is over 1GB so the column type is longtext to handle the extra size.

However, anytime I attempt to save the json blob on the java size it throws an error about the string being too long. My Code:

```
package com.cpa.ipf.bo.forecast;

import com.cpa.ipf.bo.CostCentre;
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class ForecastMetadata {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long userId;

    @ManyToOne
    private CostCentre costCentre;



    private String name;

    private Boolean viewableByAll;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ForecastStatus status;

    private LocalDateTime tsCreated;

    private LocalDateTime tsFinished;

    @Lob
    private Clob forecastBody;

    public ForecastMetadata(Long id, Long userId, CostCentre costCentre, String name, Boolean viewableByAll, ForecastStatus status, LocalDateTime tsCreated, LocalDateTime tsFinished, Clob forecastBody) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.costCentre = costCentre;
        this.name = name;
        this.viewableByAll = viewableByAll;
        this.status = status;
        this.tsCreated = tsCreated;
        this.tsFinished = tsFinished;
        this.forecastBody = forecastBody;
    }

    public ForecastMetadata() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public CostCentre getCostCentre() {
        return costCentre;
    }

    public void setCostCentre(CostCentre costCentre) {
        this.costCentre = costCentre;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean getViewableByAll() {
        return viewableByAll;
    }

    public void setViewableByAll(Boolean viewableByAll) {
        this.viewableByAll = viewableByAll;
    }

    public ForecastStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(ForecastStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTsCreated() {
        return tsCreated;
    }

    public void setTsCreated(LocalDateTime tsCreated) {
        this.tsCreated = tsCreated;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTsFinished() {
        return tsFinished;
    }

    public void setTsFinished(LocalDateTime tsFinished) {
        this.tsFinished = tsFinished;
    }

    public Clob getForecastBody() {
        return forecastBody;
    }

    public void setForecastBody(Clob forecastBody) {
        this.forecastBody = forecastBody;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ForecastMetadata that = (ForecastMetadata) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equals(userId, that.userId) &&
                Objects.equals(costCentre, that.costCentre) &&
                Objects.equals(name, that.name) &&
                Objects.equals(viewableByAll, that.viewableByAll) &&
                status == that.status &&
                Objects.equals(tsCreated, that.tsCreated) &&
                Objects.equals(tsFinished, that.tsFinished) &&
                Objects.equals(forecastBody, that.forecastBody);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, userId, costCentre, name, viewableByAll, status, tsCreated, tsFinished, forecastBody);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ForecastMetadata{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", userId=" + userId +
                ", costCentre=" + costCentre +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", viewableByAll=" + viewableByAll +
                ", status=" + status +
                ", tsCreated=" + tsCreated +
                ", tsFinished=" + tsFinished +
                ", forecastBody='" + forecastBody + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:68) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:101) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at com.mysql.cj.ClientPreparedQueryBindings.setString(ClientPreparedQueryBindings.java:628) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar!/:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.ClientPreparedQueryBindings.setCharacterStream(ClientPreparedQueryBindings.java:335) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar!/:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.ClientPreparedQueryBindings.setCharacterStream(ClientPreparedQueryBindings.java:366) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar!/:8.0.20]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1519) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar!/:8.0.20]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$4$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2818) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$4.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3025) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: This looks like a reason `Requested array size exceeds VM limit`

Comment: May be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java

Comment: This is not a heap size issue. The issue is that it's a 2GB json and attempting to build it as an array breaks java. My Heap Size is at 60GB for testing purposes.

Comment: Are you sure the heap allocated to the JVM is 60GB ?

Comment: Yeah 100% sure. If I don't allocate a large enough heap it fails with a slightly different vm error

Answer (score 2):

I see a lot of comments saying you should increase the heap size, but the error message

> Requested array size exceeds VM limit

actually means an attempt was made to create an array whose **length** would have exceeded the platform-specific maximum possible array **length** (which is usually around `Integer.MAX_VALUE`). Increasing the heap size will **not** help. It's not a limit on the *size* of an array in memory, but rather, on the *maximum valid index* an array can have.

Now, let's see the code that is causing the issue:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder((int) (x.length() * 1.1));
```

In the code above, `x` represents the contents of your `Clob` as a `String`. The constructor of `StringBuilder` delegates to `AbstractStringBuilder` constructor, which looks like this:

```
AbstractStringBuilder(int capacity) {
        if (COMPACT_STRINGS) {
            value = new byte[capacity];
            coder = LATIN1;
        } else {
            value = StringUTF16.newBytesFor(capacity);
            coder = UTF16;
        }
    }
```

Here we see the issue, plain as day: the size of the `String` representing your `CLOB` must be so dangerously close to the maximum array length limit, that 1.1 times its size exceeds the limit.

Now, let's see if we can prevent MySQL Connector from trying to initialize such an array (note that we should also aim for MySQL Connector not initializing `x`, since `String` is also represented as an array internally, and your data already got dangerously close to the array size limit). Moving up the stack a little bit to `ClientPreparedQueryBindings.setCharacterStream()`, we get:

```
boolean useLength = this.useStreamLengthsInPrepStmts.getValue();
String forcedEncoding = this.session.getPropertySet().getStringProperty(PropertyKey.clobCharacterEncoding).getStringValue();
if (useLength && (length != -1)) {
    c = new char[length];
    int numCharsRead = Util.readFully(reader, c, length); // blocks until all read
    if (forcedEncoding == null) {
        setString(parameterIndex, new String(c, 0, numCharsRead));
    } else {
        setBytes(parameterIndex, StringUtils.getBytes(new String(c, 0, numCharsRead), forcedEncoding));
    }
} else {
    c = new char[4096];
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    while ((len = reader.read(c)) != -1) {
        buf.append(c, 0, len);
    }
    if (forcedEncoding == null) {
        setString(parameterIndex, buf.toString());
    } else {
        setBytes(parameterIndex, StringUtils.getBytes(buf.toString(), forcedEncoding));
    }
}
```

Looking at the code, it seems you are out of luck. You could try to force the execution to jump into one of the other branches of the `if` statement (using MySql connection properties), but no matter where you go, a large array the size of your input is eventually going to be created.

You *might* be better off using a `BLOB`, since `setBinaryStream()` is implemented as follows:

```
public void setBinaryStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x, int length) {
        if (x == null) {
            setNull(parameterIndex);
        } else {
            this.bindValues[parameterIndex].setNull(false);
            this.bindValues[parameterIndex].setIsStream(true);
            this.bindValues[parameterIndex].setMysqlType(MysqlType.BLOB); // TODO use length to find the right BLOB type
            this.bindValues[parameterIndex].setStreamValue(x, length);
        }
    }
```

...but unfortunately, you would need to implement that `TODO` yourself, to get a `LONGBLOB` instead of `BLOB`. I suppose it all boils down to how badly you want to put that 2GB-sized blob into MySQL using the JDBC driver, which is clearly not suited for the job.

Comment: Yeah I'm gonna be honest: When I started down this path I didn't expect the JSON objects to be so big. I might consider breaking the JSON object up into smaller parts, because this has the potential to get even bigger. Thank you so much, I was scratching my head for a while at this